# Need Python Code to Copy SourceFile > DestinationFile using Variable FileName from a List

Tags: python, copying

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile
```

#### change to my working directory

```
os.chdir('Z:/')
```

#### confirm my current working directory

```
print (os.getcwd())
```

#### this is the file source I would like to copy

```
infile = open("NFO.nfo","r")
```

#### this reads into "file_nfo" all the "file names" with NFO extension that I am trying to copy using the "shutil.copy" to copy SourceFile > DestinationFile

```
for f in os.listdir ():
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    file_nfo = file_name+'.nfo'
    print (file_nfo)
    shutil.copyfile (infile, file_nfo)
```

#### copyfile (infile, outfile) - this is not working - any help is appreciated - I would like to thank you in advance for taking the time to read this.

#### this closes the SourceFile

```
infile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

`infile` is a file *object*, but `copyfile()` requires file *names*.

If you want to copy the same source file every time, use the name:

```
shutil.copyfile ("NFO.nfo", file_nfo)
```